# What is the name of this diagram?

Tags: database, uml, diagram, activity-diagram

I've had difficulties in finding a tool to create a similar diagram, a navigation model, as here [the following](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/laine/infoht/ohjeita.html) for instance, where

```
aloitussivu = homepage
yritysinfo = about
yleiskuva = general
tunnussivu = user
rekisteröintisivu = register
...
```

I use VP-UML. However, I have not managed to create such a diagram by it.

The diagram looks like an activity diagram, but I have not managed to create a similar one by the tools in VP-UML.

**What is the name of the following diagram such that I can create one?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a navigation model (also known as a hypertext model). This is not one of the UML standard diagrams but all design methods for web applications (e.g. WebML) support this diagram (and in fact, it is the most important for them).

(this does not mean that it cannot be draw in UML but I think you would find useful to take a loot at navigation models first)

Comment: Do you know any software for OSX or Ubuntu to make such diagrams?

Comment: Not really. ArgoUWE/MagicUWE was developed in Java but it is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a diagram displaying the options to navigate a web page. If you want to do this in UML you can do it by using a state diagram. Pages are states with the links being transitions.

It would look very different, but it display the same information, and if you want with more detail.

Comment: +1 Only sensible answer so far, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an elaborated use-case diagram, in which some use cases are using deeper use cases. Might also be an object-participation diagram.

Comment: Might not be either. If you are referring to UML use cases, it certainly isn't. I've never heard of a "participation" diagram.

Answer (score 2):

If I were making a diagram of that type, I'd probably use MS Visio, which has many tools for creating diagrams like that (flowcharts and the like).

Comment: It appears to be a Visio format to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a [mind-mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map) program to make something like htat

[freemind is a pretty good one](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Answer (score 1):

This is called Use Case Diagrams in UML. There are so many tools to draw them ranging from commercial to free. You may try Violet. Download it from here.
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/violet/

Comment: It is not a use case diagram - no actors.

Comment: sorry, It slipped my mind. thanks for pointing out. Can we call it a data flow diagram?

Comment: Probably not. Classical DFDs actually explicitly identify data as separate entities in the diagram, which this doesn't seem to do. I think as Jens suggests its a navigation diagram of some sort.

Comment: Rather that data flow diagram, I would more likely term it a user-flow diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://writemaps.com/ if you want to generate a simple sitemap.

Otherwise you'll need to delve into visio or a visio equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Since a few people mentioned Visio, [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) is a free alternative.  It's not the greatest, but it gets the job done.

> Dia is inspired by the commercial
>   Windows program 'Visio', though more
>   geared towards informal diagrams for
>   casual use. It can be used to draw
>   many different kinds of diagrams. It
>   currently has special objects to help
>   draw entity relationship diagrams, UML
>   diagrams, flowcharts, network
>   diagrams, and many other diagrams. It
>   is also possible to add support for
>   new shapes by writing simple XML
>   files, using a subset of SVG to draw
>   the shape.